# c# windows form calling webservices concurrently

Tags: c#, web-services

There is a multithread in windows form client to call a webservice method.

I expect to call the web method concurrently in multithread but instead the function calls are in queue to execute at web service.

This is not a WCF, where should i add the Connection limit? or something like that?

Comment: How are you determining that the web service is only processing one at a time?

Comment: @ChrisLively , i wrote a simulation program and confirm with that. same situation with this post (but he is using WCF) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990469/web-service-not-handling-multiple-simultaneous-request-from-same-application-wit

Comment: @Rafa, what pointers you are refering to?

Comment: Please give some information about your web service and your client, otherwise I cannot help you.

Comment: I was probably not clear in my question.  Where is the Web Service running?  Is it in a visual studio instance in debug mode on your local computer or is it actually installed under IIS on a server?

Answer (score 0):

Server Site: .net 2.0 Web Service asmx

Client Site: Windows Form Application

By adding the below setting to the app.config in client (windows form), you can define the connection limit to the web service.

The connection limit is not working in localhost, so put the web service in another host to test.

```
<system.net>
   <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="24"/>       
   </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```